# PHP rollback method has failed

Tags: php, mysql, rollback

I have tried this piece of code and unfortunately rollback method failed!
Thank in advance!!

```
$bash = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','dbastegoi');
$bash->autocommit(FALSE);

echo 'timologio';
$r =$bash->query("INSERT INTO tbparastatika (strArithmos, fkERGO, strPROMITH, sngCOST, intTYPOS, intDRASH) VALUES ('1','1001','123123123',800138,1,1)");
//ΕΙΣΑΓΩΓΗ ΤΙΜΟΛΟΓΙΟΥ
 $i = $bash->insert_id;
ECHO PHP_EOL;
echo 'dapanh';
try {
    $r =$bash->query("INSERT INTO tbdapanes_stegash (idPARASTATnIKO, sngCOST, fkDIAMERISMA, intMONTH) VALUES ($i,100,1,1)");
    echo $r;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'error2';
}

$bash->commit();
$bash->rollback();

//$SYNDESH->commit();
//$SYNDESH->rollback();
$bash->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not make a commit first and then a roolback. You have to make a commit if your query runs without error or make a rollback if you get an error:

```
try {
    $r =$bash->query("INSERT INTO tbdapanes_stegash (idPARASTATnIKO, sngCOST, fkDIAMERISMA, intMONTH) VALUES ($i,100,1,1)");
    echo $r;
    $bash->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'error2';
    $bash->rollback();
}
```

Comment: Should I have use catch for each query?

Comment: @ΛάζαροςΚώτσικας It depends on what your transaction should be.

Comment: On the above piece of code you think that I should have used rollback  and at the first query?

Comment: @ΛάζαροςΚώτσικας a rollback only makes sence if you have a transaction with more then one statement. The rollack rolls all queries ack that was successful to until you call the rollback and which are nor committed. For one single query it makes no sence to roll it back.

Comment: I know that but unfortunately has failed again :)!

Comment: No!! but i know that the second query has an error in its syntax.

Comment: In fact it doesn't catch second error but it returns false!